How to create different sizetables for each type of clothing?
Im making marketplace on django and cant realize how to solve the problem:
I got class Product(class for clothes) and i need to create another class for Sizes of different categories of clothes, for example:
Shoes will got - 9US, 10US, 11US...
Shirts will got - XS, S, M, L...
etc.
When a person wants to post a product, he will first indicate its category, and after that he will be offered a choice of those sizes that will belong to the selected category, that is, the sizes should depend on the category
How can i create that type of class??
My Product class:
class Product(models.Model):
    class ModerationStatuses(models.TextChoices):
        DRAFT = 'DR', _('черновик')
        ON_MODERATION = 'MD', _('На модерации')
        APPROVED = 'AP', _('Одобрено')
        REJECTED = 'RJ', _('Отклонено')

    class ConditionStatuses(models.TextChoices):
        NEW = 'NEW', _('New')
        USED = 'USD', _('Used')
        VERY_WORN = 'VW', _('Very worn')
        NOT_SPECIFIED = 'NS', _('Not specified')

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    city = ...
    style = models.ForeignKey(Style, related_name='category_products', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='style_products', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField()
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False)
    modification = models.OneToOneField('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,
                                        help_text='When editing an approved item a modification is created. This '
                                                  'modification is sent for moderation and, after approval, replaces '
                                                  'the original position.')
    is_modification = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    moderation_status = models.CharField(choices=ModerationStatuses.choices, default=ModerationStatuses.DRAFT,
                                         null=False, max_length= 2)
    condition = models.CharField(choices=ConditionStatuses.choices, default=ConditionStatuses.NEW, null=False, max_length=3)
    posted_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

I literally cant find any info to solve my problem(((

I make your Product class a bit more simpler to do so :
models.py
class Product(models.Model):
    title    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price    = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    
    def size(self):
       return Size.objects.filter(product=self)

class Size(models.Model):
    product    = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title      = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

admin.py
class SizeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Size

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'price')
    inlines = [SizeInline]

This way you can add size or any other features that you want.
views.py
def allProduct(request):
    p = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, "products.html", {"products":p})


def singleProduct(request, pk):
    p = Product.objects.get(pk=pk)
    s = Size.objects.filter(product=p.pk)
    return render(request, "product.html", {'product':p,'size':s})


at this solution i’ll need to add sizes to each product, but I want to do the following, when a person wants to post a product, he will first indicate its category, and after that he will be offered a choice of those sizes that will belong to the selected category, so sizes z should depend on the category

so products sizes are not predefined ? You mean the user should enter them by its own?

sizes should be predefined for seller, he can choose one of sizes that his clothing got, it’s marketplace, not shop, sorry for my mistake

so my code will handle it in a better way, just test that out! and for views, you can check the code that I generate in the answer.

thank u so much!its really great solution and more simple that i was imaging!

so mark it as your answer for others ... good luck
